# External shared memory vs internal shared memory

Tags: c++, c, memory, multiprocessing, shared-memory

i can't seen to find literature on these.

First, am I right in assuming that external shared memory is shared memory created by the kernel?

And internal shared memory is shared memory created by a process/es?

Regardless of whether this assumption is correct, what are a few advantages and disadvantages of using one over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: In what context are you seeing the terms "internal shared memory" and "external shared memory"?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @JoeZ we were given this topic in relation to multiprocessing? Am i missing something?

Comment: I suspect your professor has a specific concept he/she is trying to express with these terms.  You'll have to review the lecture notes and/or your text book.  These terms could mean anything.  For example "intra-process" vs. "inter-process" shared memory, local vs. remote memory pools in a NUMA environment, file-backed vs. anonymous memory mappings...